# Unlike postman, getting slow powershell script performance when used to interact with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to use a PS script to start using Graph API:

```
$clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$TenantName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"
$tokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    Client_Id     = $clientId
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
}
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenBody
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($tokenResponse.access_token)"} -Uri $URL -Method Get -Verbose
($result | select-object Value).Value | Select-Object id
```

I am not sure if it is the script or something else but the success rate for this script is 20%. Most of the time the return is either delayed or timed out.

We are getting consistent results when we use postman to interact with the graph API. How come powershell is giving us a hard time? Is there something that we need to change on our script?

Thanks

Comment: Here is the PS script:

Comment: Any reason why you're not using Microsoft graph PowerShell? Also which version of PowerShell are you using? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell

Comment: I am running powershell on linux. I am new to it so I hope that answers your question. By the way, I think I found the root cause. The machine I was executing the ps script on is located in Australia and my subscription with Mic is in US. I may be wrong but I think that is the reason for the delay because when I run the script from an Azure linux VM in US region, I get a return every time and fast. But my next challenge is to figure out why the graph api teams reports are showing different values than the ones I see on their Analytics dashboards. message count, user count etc are different

Comment: the Microsoft Graph PowerShell module is based on ps core. Which means it'll run on linux :)
The inconsistencies you are seeing across regions are to be expected because the data needs to replicate. Stack overflow works better if you ask one question per "post" so it's easier to answer. I suggest breaking it down into multiple posts.